# Add a second background-image to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am wondering whether it is possible to assign second background-image to element through CSS3 or jQuery/js.

To make it clear am I aware I can make it this way:

```
 .someElement { background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png); }
```

The thing is I need to do it something like this:

```
 .someElement             { background-image: url(sheep.png); }
 .someElement.secondClass { background-image: url(betweengrassandsky.png); }
```

The problem is this will just overwrite the first background-image instead of combining them.
Is there any solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve here? To have them side-by-side? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to repeat the first background image as you show in your first line of CSS.

If you want, you can check `.someElement` to see if it has the second class, and apply it using jQuery:

```
$('.someElement').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('secondClass')) {
        var background = $(this).css('background-image');
        $(this).css('background-image', background + ', url(betweengrassandsky.png)');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 .someElement             { background-image: url(sheep.png); }
 .someElement.secondClass { background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png); }
```

Comment: The first background-image is dynamic in my case.