# Merge two classes background image for one element

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to add two classes to one element with two different background images positioned on its different space. But when I apply another class it is overriding first class background image. See below

```
<li class="first">

li.first {background:url(images/first.png)no-repeat center top}
li.second{background:url(images/second.png)no-repeat right center}
```

So I want to merge both background when apply both class on li element like

```
<li class="first second">
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Similar to this (but not a dupe)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457820/add-a-second-background-image-to-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways.

You could add the second background not to the element itself, but to a pseudo-element absolutely positioned such that it fully covers the `li`. However, if you wish to do this for more than three classes & backgrounds, then this method doesn't work as you can only have two pseudo-elements (`:before` and `:after`).

Or you could simply add the first background to the second class as well.

[**DEMOS**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3413901)

In both cases, the HTML would be something like:

```
<li class="first second"></li>
```

The relevant CSS in the first case:

```
li { 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}
.first {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(102,37,93,.95) 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 50% 0;
}
.second {
    position: relative;
}
.second:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,0,0,.9));
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
    content: '';
}
```

... and in the second case:

```
li { 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}
.first {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(102,37,93,.95) 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 50% 0;
}
.second {
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,0,0,.9)), 
        linear-gradient(rgba(102,37,93,.95) 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position: 100% 50%, 50% 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.., this can be one of the solution.. let me try and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested elements like as follows, if you have control of your markup.

```
li {background:url(images/first.png)no-repeat center top}
li span {background:url(images/second.png)no-repeat right center; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

<li><span></span></li>
```

Comment: Since your answer is also promising but it is required one more element so I would rather go with css. However giving up voting. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes on the same element, the second is always having more priority and overriding the first.

You should use CSS3 multiple background images to achieve the effect:

```
li.multi-bg{
    background-image: url(images/first.png), url(images/second.png);
    background-position: center bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have to use two different classes

Comment: Then you should use nested elements for different backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

If by "merge", you mean you'd like `<li class="first second">` to have *both* background images applied, you can use CSS 3 background images to achieve this. I find [this page on CSS3 Info](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) is a really good resource for using it.

Beware, as always with newer CSS features, browser support is not as widespread. The above page lists the browser support as:

> Firefox has supported multiple backgrounds since version 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2), Safari since version 1.3, Chrome since version 10, Opera since version 10.50 (Presto 2.5) and Internet Explorer since version 9.0.

The basic implementation of BG images is simply:

```
.someElement {
  background: url(x.png) 0 0 repeat-x, url(y.png) 10 10 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I know to use multiple background on one single class but I am talking about merging two classes background images on one element at a time.

Comment: Ah, in which case, I don't think you can do that.